# Proper way to manage modules in Angular when using pipes?

Tags: angular, import, module, pipe

I am using a pipe in Angular like:

custom-component.ts:

```
<custom-component
  [placeholder]="text | myPipe" 
>
</custom-component>
```

The thing is this component is imported into a module we are gonna call Module1, and Module1 is imported in Module2.

But, the myPipe is also in Module2 but not in Module1, so Angular can't find the pipe.

The folder structure is something like:

```
shared
     components
          custom-component
          ...
          module1.module.ts

     pipes
          myPipe.ts
     
     module2.module.ts
```

What is the proper way to import the pipe? And would prefer to keep the pipe at the folder pipes because its used in some other places in the application. Thanks in advance c:

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need three modules:

- FeatureAModule
- FeatureBModule
- SharedModule (or CoreModule)

Each feature module contains components/pipes/services/etc that are specific to that feature. Anything that's needed by multiple features belongs in your Shared module. For example, your pipe will be in the `declarations` and `exports` array in your Shared module. Your Shared module will then be imported into your feature modules, enabling access to the pipe.

Angular has some good [documentation on sharing modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) that's worth a read as well.

I'd also like to share with you my personal preference for organizing the codebase as well. As I said, this is my opinion on this, so others may disagree, but I've found it to be helpful when working with large teams.

Essentially the codebase is organized like so:

```
/src/
   /app/
       /shared/
           /components/
           /pipes/
           /services/
           /resolvers/
           /shared.module.ts
       /feature-one/
           /components/
           /pipes/
           /services/
           /resolvers/
           /feature-one-routing.module.ts
           /feature-one.module.ts
       /feature-two/
           /components/
           /pipes/
           /services/
           /resolvers/
           /feature-two-routing.module.ts
           /feature-two.module.ts
       /app.component.ts
       /app-routing.module.ts
       /app.module.ts
```

Every module has the same set of folders, named after various Angular building blocks (component, service, interceptor, resolver, pipe, etc).
The general rule of thumb for your team would be: Are you creating a `service`? put it in the `services` folder**.

I like this pattern because regardless of what feature or module you're working in, the organization is the same. Every Angular developer is familiar with those concepts, so it's extremely easy to find things. It's also abundantly clear which thing belongs to which module. By imposing an easy structure, you don't end up with modules organized in all different ways - that would cause quite the headache!

You should also feel free to break the "shared" module into many smaller modules. For example you may choose to break down each shared component into it's own module. [For example how ngx-bootstrap does it](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components) - they have an `AccordionModule` and a `ModalsModule`, which would all be "shared" amongst your feature modules, but imported as needed. Maybe a particular feature module doesn't need an accordion, so it doesn't import the module! In this case I would still follow the same pattern of having folders named after the Angular building blocks.

** I also like to note that I consider this a *soft* rule. For example, if you've created some complicated component that has a lot of logic you've encapsulated in a service...it's reasonable to put the service in the same folder as the component. On the flip side, if you've created a service that's injected in many places, that would belong in the `services` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion It is all depends complexity of your application.

You can create one big `SharedModule`. Declare all your pipes, common components and directives then export everthing.

Ideally dividing your shared elements (components, pipes, directives) into smaller modules which forming a whole when all together. Such as `AlertsModule`, `DataTableModule`, `CurrencyModule` and so on. Which makes your atomic components more managable in a low to large scale application with a very efficent cost.